# Recovering data from HDD after failed FS change attempt

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, data-recovery, external-hdd

I lost partition on my 5TB Seagate Backup Plus external HDD. I was trying to convert the file system from NTFS to HFS using Paragon HDD Manager 17. Windows is not recognizing the drive and MacOS is recognizing the drive with an empty HFS partition and is unable mount the partition.

I do have a backup of the drive available in the AWS Glacier. But, if I am able to recover the data from the drive. It will save me the hassle of retrieving TBs of data from Glacier.

So, I am planning to use `photorec` to recover the files to a new drive.

Is this the approach I should go ahead with? Or is there any better way to recover files?

Another question I have is - is there any way I can recover the directory structure?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about a Windows-formatted hard drive, broken by a windows tool.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am recovering it on a UNIX machine and tools I am using to recover data will be performed on a UNIX system.

Comment: `photorec` or any other recovery tool may have problems when files are split on the drive. I once had deleted several music files and upon recovery ended up with a lot of half songs that would need manual merging. I assume that retrieving the files from the backup location might me more robust and hassle-free.